# Places to Test Player Interest In Storyline

Tags: community-management

I am working on an iPad game, and have a few different intro story lines. I would like to get gamer feedback on the intros.

What websites or techniques have others used to get such feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can break it down into just text, one of the common things some companies do is send out surveys to a bunch of people asking them to rate it.

So basically just make a surveymonkey survey (or some online equivalent) and ask the user to rate the intro text on some kind of scale to see what sticks.

Generally speaking, though, these companies would have systems in place for beta testing lists so they already have a large pool of people they can spam who opted in to getting these kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

Invite only beta. Find about 5-10 main beta testers and give them each 5-10 invites to give to their friends, on the condition that they will give feedback.

Oh, and *anyone* can be a beta tester. Your grandma, your next door neighbour kid, anyone you see as a target audience for your game.

Comment: What if the game is a many months from being ready to play. Have you had experience starting beta testers at the beginning of the project?

Comment: oh i misunderstood your question then...